# What does רייה mean in והיו ימי רייה מ"ד שנה?

Tags: hebrew

What does רייה mean in  והיו ימי רייה מ"ד שנה?

Thank you!

Comment: Perhaps you could clarify where you saw this?

Comment: @DonielF, it is written on my grandmother's matzeva, almost 35 years ago. I suspect there could be an error, or else, it means something extraordinary that I am uncertain about. It's obviously very meaningful to me, and we need to decide if it needs correcting. That was my purpose of posting on this forum.  It's not just a translation being sought. Thanks!

Comment: In that case I think I agree with the close votes. This seems to be more about Hebrew and less about Judaism. I also suspect that @Temp is correct, that the Reish is a cut-off Ches.

Comment: @DonielF, I thought the question could have a basis here, with respect to using the "hebrew" tag (which exists). If in fact the Ches is not just cut-off (e.g. maybe it's a phrase used in Judaism that fits this context).

Comment: Hebrew, as used in Judaism. Translating a passuk would be on-topic. Translating a brachah, perhaps. But I'm not sure that translating a random gravestone would be.

Comment: @DonielF, thanks point taken! I guess, my interpretation was this is a common phrase used amongst "Jewish" tombstones?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a corrupted Ches (Chet), and if so means 'of her life' in this context.

Comment: @DonielF: It seems to me that this  answers the question.

Comment: @DonielF - This answers the question well. No use tracking down a word that doesn't exist. It's logical that the word is חיים in the original phrase.